# Adjust tabulator row height in different tables

Tags: javascript, css, tabulator

I have 2 tabulator tables in then same page (#tableC id="Cuentas" and #tableM id="Movimientos") and every table should have differente row height.

I have tried in CCS file

```
tableC.tabulator-row.tabulator-cell { height:40px;} 
tableM.tabulator-row.tabulator-cell { height:100px;}
```

and

```
#Cuentas.tabulator-row.tabulator-cell { height:40px;} 
#Movimientos.tabulator-row.tabulator-cell { height:100px;}
```

and

```
tableC.tabulator-row.element.style { height:40px;} 
tableM.tabulator-row.element-style { height:100px;}
```

**and several combinations more**, 
None of them works

If I write

```
.tabulator-row.tabulator-cell { height:40px;}
```

if fixes the row height for all the tables in page

How can I do different row height for different tables

Comment: Can you include the HTML?

Comment: Did you have a space after ```#Cuantas``` ? In the code above, the CSS selector seem to select element with both ```#Cuantas``` and ```.tabulator-row ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a space between id selector and class selector.

```
#Cuentas .tabulator-row { height:10px;} 
#Movimientos .tabulator-row { height:40px;}
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/FlamFilo/0y2mga6o/3/

See : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. That way, people who find the question using search engine can have more assurance that the answer is correct